# Missing btusb.ko module when compiling OpenWrt

Tags: kernel, openwrt

I wanted to build OpenWrt following this tutorial:

https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/blogs/663/6lowpan-for-bluetooth-low-energy-on-openwrt/

However during compilation I get following error: `ERROR: module '/home/mkru/Desktop/lowpan/openwrt/build_dir/target-mipsel_mips32_musl-1.1.14/linux-brcm47xx_generic/linux-3.18.29/drivers/bluetooth/btusb.ko' is missing.`

I have tried using menuconfig but btusb does not appear in Kernel modules -> USB Support or Kernel modules -> Other modules tab.

In directory `/home/mkru/Desktop/lowpan/openwrt/build_dir/target-mipsel_mips32_musl-1.1.14/linux-brcm47xx_generic/linux-3.18.29/drivers/bluetooth/`

I can find file btusb.c but it looks like it was not compiled into btusb.ko during building process.

I am not familiar with all linux kernel building issues and I do not know how to solve my problem in correct way. Can I just manually compile this one file?

Answer (score 0):

The Linux kernel has a build configuration file that enables you to select the features that you do and do not want.  You need to select that feature.

From the root if your source tree, you can do:

```
# make menuconfig
```

At that point, you can type `/` followed by `CONFIG_BT_HCIBTUSB` and press enter.  You should see something like:

```
Symbol: BT_HCIBTUSB [=n]                                                                                                                                          
Type  : tristate
Prompt: HCI USB driver
Location:
  -> Networking support (NET [=y])
(1)   -> Bluetooth subsystem support (BT [=n])
        -> Bluetooth device drivers
  Defined at drivers/bluetooth/Kconfig:21
  Depends on: NET [=y] && BT [=n] && USB [=y]
  Selects: BT_INTEL [=n]
```

At that point, pressing `1` will take you to the configuration option marked `(1)`:

```
< > HCI USB driver (NEW)
```

Pressing space once will configure it to build as a module.  Pressing space a second time will select it be built into the kernel image:

```
<*> HCI USB driver (NEW)
```

Now, when you exit the configuration tool and rebuild the kernel, that optional feature will be included in the build.